# Invalidate Cache using VaryByCustom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, cache-invalidation

I want to invalidate cache using VaryByCustom attribute.
Following code is being used for cache setup.

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg))
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            return context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

Comment: So where have you put this code, what's not working?

Comment: I've put it in Global.asx. I want to invalidate the cache base on the VaryByCustom attribute that this method gets as arg.

Comment: Essentially, I want to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196309/how-to-invalidate-cache-using-asp-net-mvc-4-0-donutoutputcache-varybycustom but without using the MvcDonutCaching package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using it like this:

Make sure you decorate your action with attribute:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByCustom = 
  "YourStringThatIsArgParamInYourGlobalAsaxMethod")]
  public ActionResult MyActionOnTheController(string myParam)
 {
 }
```